# How to get the amount of Eth a particular address sent to a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, web3-providers

Goodday Everyone….So am building a dapp where different addresses can send ether to a smart contract…So am trying to get the value of ether sent by each addresses through a function….How do I write that function??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are trying to get the value of ether sent by each addresses through a function.

You can use:

```
receive() external payable {}

fallback() external payable {}
```

See: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/contracts.html

Comment: I think this function gives only the balance of the total Ether that address has.....I want to be able to receive ether from different addresses, then limit how much that particular address can withdraw based on the amount they sent to that smart contract.

Comment: If that is the case, you need the fallback or receive function. Both functions allow you to receive ether from different addresses. I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to store the address of the sender in a data structure while receiving the ETH, you can go with the `array`.

Along with that, you need a `mapping` in the form of `address->uint` to store the amount of ETH sent by each sender.

Then just simply create a view function that when passed with the array index returns the ETH sent by a particular sender.